# Can't access laptop BIOS when SSD is plugged in

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

I've been struggling with this for a couple hours now.

I recently bought a new SSD to replace the HDD that came with my laptop (Lenovo S510p Touch). I wanted a fresh install so I connected the SSD to my desktop and installed Windows 8 on it with no problems; it was even bootable (on my desktop). However, when I swapped my laptop's internal HDD for the SSD and turned it on, I faced nothing but a blank screen; not even a BIOS.

If I put in the old HDD again, it starts normally. Strangely, if I remove the SSD and have nothing in the disk bay, the BIOS is accessible and asks for a boot device. I have experimented with hot plugging the SSD in after booting from the W8 install disk, but the laptop system/BIOS refuses to recognize the SSD as far as I can tell.

Any ideas? I am 99% sure the SSD is not at fault unless I damaged it in my latest hot-plug experiment. The core problem of the BIOS not being accessible when the SSD is plugged in is definitely not the SSD's fault.

Comment: Have you ever found out how to use the SSD? I have the same problem with a Lenovo.

Answer (score -1):

The bios settings may be different to motherboard to motherboard. You can install the OS when the new SSD is connected to your Laptop and try booting it up.

The problem might be because of the different motherboard on the different systems.

Comment: I highly doubt if the SSD will be detected if the OS is installed when the SSD is connected to the laptop. I'd be happy if it even recognizes it in the first place. Something else is wrong

Answer (score -2):

Your desktop peripheral is different from your laptop peripheral. So, when you install or load an operating system your operating system gets configured with respect to the peripheral hardware which it is installed on including the motherboard. So to avoid such a situation you should there are two ways to fix your problem. 1) clone your operating system from your laptop hdd to your new ssd. You may find many software that does this job pretty easy.
Try googling. 2) install your preferred operating system by connecting your ssd to your laptop (where you want your new ssd to be installed).

Comment: I'm wondering if this answer is what the OP is looking for.  This answer certainly throws no light on "BIOS not being accessible" part of the problem